# iOS 9,10 NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl

I am getting this error on iOS 9 and iOS 10.

`2017-02-22 18:38:44.955295 xxxxxx[8511:301107] [] nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9801]
2017-02-22 18:38:44.958 xxxxxx[8511:301106] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)`

Here my NSAppTransportSecurity config. I have put everything that I found about this issue:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>domain1</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>domain2</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I put them all, I don't know why it still not working.

Comment: Are you really making requests of domains called "domain1" and "domain2"?  Or, have you substituted those in this question because the domains are confidential?  If it's neither of those, then be advised that most of this TLS configuration applies to nonsense domains.

Comment: @danh No I am just changing domains name for confidential reasons.